# Is it safe to use System.Drawing.Common 4.7.3?

Tags: .net, cross-platform, .net-6.0, system.drawing, system.drawing.common

Until recently my project had a dependency on [System.Drawing.Common version 4.5.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.5.1), and it seemed to work fine both on Windows and on Linux. But then I noticed the security warning and decided to upgrade. At first I upgraded to the latest stable release which is [version 7.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/7.0.0), but then I started to get warnings and `PlatformNotSupportedException` and noticed [this article by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only).

I considered changing to one the alternative libraries that they recommend there, but I released that this is not a trivial change. Moreover, while my use of this library is pretty simple (mainly loading, saving and converting images to Base64), my project is a shared library that the entire company uses and I try not to break backward compatibility, which replacing the library would cause.

Finally, I looked at all of [the versions of System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) and I noticed that while version 6 and 7 are not usable on Linux, version 5 is marked as deprecated and versions 4.7.1 and below are marked to have critical vulnerabilities, **specifically versions 4.7.2 and [4.7.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.7.3) are not marked as deprecated nor having critical vulnerabilities and seem to work fine.**

So is it safe to continue using version 4.7.3, or is it just a mistake that it's not marked as deprecated or having vulnerabilities?